# Slow rendering of datatables from api

Tags: ajax, datatables

I'm loading in some records via an api and then displaying them in a DataTable. I'm unable to control the request, I just get the data back in json format via a post request. This works fine but with larger data sets it's taking a while to render the data. Is there any way I can stagger the load other than at server side? This is the code I'm currently using.

function register(token) {

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://apilink',
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + token);
    },
    complete: function () {                     
        $('#table-register').dataTable({
            "columnDefs": [ 
                { 'orderData':[6], 'targets': [0] },
                {
                    "targets": [ 6 ],
                    "visible": false,
                    "searchable": false
                },                  
                {
                    "render": function (data, type, row) {
                        if (row[5] == "Not Communicated") {
                            return '<span class="btn btn-xs default btn-round"><i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i> Not Communicated</span>';
                        } else if (row[5] == "Communicated") {
                            return '<span class="btn btn-xs yellow-soft btn-round"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Communicated</span>';
                        } 
                    },              
                    "sortable": true,
                    "visible": true,
                    "searchable": true,
                    "targets": [5],
                }                   
            ],                  
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            "deferRender": true,
            "buttons": [
                {
                    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                    orientation: 'landscape',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: ':visible'
                    }
                },  
                {
                    extend: 'copyHtml5',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: ':visible'
                    }
                },              
                {
                    extend: 'excelHtml5',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: ':visible'
                    }
                },  
                {
                    extend: 'csvHtml5',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: ':visible'
                    }
                }
            ],                  
        });                                 
    },
    success: function (data) {

        var userList = $.parseJSON(data);
        var trHTML = '';
        var party = $("input[name=party]").val();
        $.each(userList, function (idx, obj) {
        if (party == "MANAGER") {   
            trHTML +=
                 '<tr><td><a href="pmi.html?Ref=' + obj.inspectiondefectid + '">SMI-' + obj.sequencenumber +'</a>' +
                 '</td><td>' + obj.assistancetestserchdefect +  
                 '</td><td>' + obj.replycomment +                        
                 '</td><td>' + moment(obj.notificationdate).format('DD/MM/YYYY') +               
                 '</td><td>' + obj.createby +
                 '</td><td>' + obj.replystatus +    
                 '</td><td>' + obj.sequencenumber +                          
                 '</td></tr>';
        } else if (obj.showtasknotification != 0 && party != "MANAGER"){
            trHTML +=
                 '<tr><td><a href="pmi.html?Ref=' + obj.inspectiondefectid + '">SMI-' + obj.sequencenumber +'</a>' +
                 '</td><td>' + obj.assistancetestserchdefect +  
                 '</td><td>' + obj.replycomment +                            
                 '</td><td>' + moment(obj.notificationdate).format('DD/MM/YYYY') +               
                 '</td><td>' + obj.createby +
                 '</td><td>' + obj.replystatus +
                 '</td><td>' + obj.sequencenumber +                          
                 '</td></tr>';                      
                }
        });


        $('#table-register').append(trHTML);

    }
}).fail(function (data) {
    alert("Error");
});
```

}

Comment: The bottleneck is the "manual" construction of markup along with some really slow jQuery. You  should use dataTables builtin `ajax: {...}` instead.  Besides it will speed things up `deferRender` will have actually effect as well.

Comment: Apologies for the rookie question but how would I go about doing that?